# Spring Framework bean initialization not returning correct data from database

Tags: java, spring-framework-beans

I am updating a DAO bean in a Spring application using java. When the DAO is initialize, the initialization method (InitDao) accesses an Oracle database and return 4 rows of data from a table. The class caches the data and when the application needs the data during message processing, it uses the cached data unless the last access time was more than 15 minutes ago. When I ran the application the first time, the data was returned correctly.  I updated the data in the database and the application never uses the new data.  If I redeploy the application with a new version, even during initialization, the data is the original data.  The cache never updates.  The cache time is set and updated after 15 minutes.  The method to query the database is also run.  Yet the data does not change.

I am new to this framework so I am not entirely sure how beans are initialized and how the process works. But this is what I know.

I updated the xml file that defines the bean in this way:

```
<bean id="applicationControlDao"         
   class="tms.common.repository.appControl.cache.dao.ApplicationControlDao">
   <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
   </property>
   <property name="applications">
        <value>TRIPMESSAGINGSERVICE</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is the initialization method.

```
public void initDao() throws Exception {
        this.selectApplicationControlQuery = new ApplicationControlDao.SelectApplicationControlQuery(this.getDataSource(), "select application, appl_parm_key, parameter from tms_application_control where application = ?");
        this.applicationControlDtos = this.querySelectApplicationControl(this.selectApplicationControlQuery, this.applications);
        this.resetExpiration();
        this.lastCacheRefreshTime = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    }
```

This is how the cache is updated in the application:

```
public boolean isParameterFlagYes(String parameterKey) {
        String[] application = {MessageServiceConstants.APPLICATION_NAME};
        log.info("Last refresh time: " + applicationControlDao.getLastRefreshTime());
        List<IApplicationControlDTO> applicationControlDtoList =  applicationControlDao.selectApplicationControl(application);
        for(IApplicationControlDTO appControls : applicationControlDtoList)
        {
            log.info("App Control Parameter Key: " + appControls.getParamKey() + " Parameter Value: " + appControls.getParameter());
        }
        Optional<IApplicationControlDTO> applicationControlDto = applicationControlDtoList.stream().
                filter(p -> p.getParamKey().equals(parameterKey) &&
                        p.getParameter().equalsIgnoreCase(CoreConstants.YES_FLAG)).findAny();
        if (applicationControlDto.isPresent()) {
            log.info("App Control Flag is true for " + parameterKey );
            return true;
        }
        log.info("App Control Flag is false for " + parameterKey );
        return false;
    }
```

Why doesn't the cache clear and data get updated?
I have also tried to call a 'resetCache' method that is part of the ApplicationControlDAO and the database values do not change.  They are the original values when I first ran the application.

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I'll say is that whoever wrote this code is entirely unfamiliar with idiomatic Java and presumably Spring. Given that this was written after the introduction of Java 8, this should be using (1) Spring Boot for configuration and (2) `@Cacheable` to handle this entire business.

Comment: Yes. I agreed.  In general, the applications are not written correctly.  The class I am trying to use was written originally using Java 1.6.  With that said, can you help me get this working?  I am new to Spring and Beans so I am not sure why the call to the database does not update the cache.